# Get many values in a loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I have a 4 arrays:

```
var array1[] = {1,2,3,4}
var array2[] = {a,b,c,d}
var array3[] = {A,B,C,D}
var array4[] = {10,20,30,40}
```

Now, I want to GET 4 values from this 4 array in 1 loop, so how can do it, like this output for 1 loop:

```
"1,a,A,10"
```

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<4; i++) Console.WriteLine("\"{0},{1},{2},{3}\"", array1[i], array2[i], array3[i], array4[i]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you wanted :

```
var array2[] = {'a','b','c','d'};
var array3[] = {'A','B','C','D'};
```

by your 2nd and 3rd arrays

anyway you can loop through them as mentioned in the comment

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine("\"{0},{1},{2},{3}\"", array1[i], array2[i], array3[i], array4[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) 
{
 String a = String.Format("\"{0},{1},{2},{3}\"", array1[i], array2[i], array3[i], array4[i]);

 // Do what you want with the value here
}
```

Comment: For whoever downvote this solution, can you give us some hints why ? as I don't see any difference between this solution and the above one which has been upvoted ?

Answer (score 0):

`another way` is to `put all arrays into one array and loop through it`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Object[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        Object[] array2 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
        Object[] array3 = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
        Object[] array4 = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
        var arrays = new Object[][] { array1, array2, array3, array4 };
        string str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Length; i++)
        {
            str += arrays[i][0].ToString()+',';
        }
        str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

**Output:** 1,a,A,10